# Spring Data envers: How to get value REVTYPE from revision object

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate-envers, spring-data-envers

I am trying to implement auditing of entity using spring data envers. I am able to obtain all or single Revision object for entity as

```
Revisions<Integer, User> revisions = userRepository.findRevisions(id);
```

I want to get REVTYPE value for particular revision but I don't find any method in `Revision` class. I can see value of REVTYPE in user_aud table.

How can I get REVTYPE of a Revision?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Object[]> list = auditReader.createQuery()
//  Creates a query, which selects the revisions, at which the given entity was modified.
    .forRevisionsOfEntity(entityClass, entityClass.getName(), false, true)
// false for Entities only, true for selectDeletedEntities
    .add(AuditEntity.revisionNumber().eq(revision)).getResultList();
// Array will contain entity, entity information and revision type.
```

Comment: thanks for response. I know it is possible to get retype value using hibernate auditReader. Since, I am using spring data envers, so, I wanted to get type of Revision from `Revision` object which is returned by methods of `RevisionRepository`.

Comment: I believe you can't query directly from Revision object.

Comment: Yes. u are right. I did go through source code of RevisionRepositoryImpl, But I can't find any method returning REVTYPE.

Comment: You are welcome. Maybe you can contribute or suggest(request feature) to Spring Team. But in general, why not to use auditReader?

Answer (score 0):

Since Version 2.2.0, you can do this:

```
revision.getMetadata().getRevisionType()
```

See [Javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api//org/springframework/data/history/RevisionMetadata.html#getRevisionType--).